# How to write an algorithm in algorithm environment in Latex?

Tags: lists, algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmic, algpseudocode

How do I write the following algorithm/pseudocode in algorithm environment in  Latex?

```
train_ANN(fi,wi,oj)
For epochs from 1 to N
       While (j<=m)
       Randomly initialize wi={w1,w2…..wn}
       input oj={o1,o2…..om} in the input layer
       forward propagate (fi*wi) through layers until getting the predicted result y
       compute e=y-y^
       back propagate e from right to left through layers
            update wi
       end
```

Comment: Hi Anurag, could you put your exact question in your posting? I'm guessing you're struggeling to write pseudocode/an algorithm in the algorithm environment?

Comment: Hello, please review the proposed answer, If you like it and/or it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓)

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Text of the caption}\label{your_label}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \STATE  $\mathrm{train\_ANN} (f_i,w_i,o_j)$
        \FOR{epochs = $1$ to $N$}
            \WHILE{$(j\le m)$}
                \STATE Randomly initialize $w_i=\{w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n\}$
                \STATE input $o_j=\{o_1,o_2,\dots,o_m\}$ in the input layer
                \STATE forward propagate $(f_i\cdot w_i)$ through layers until getting the predicted result $y$
                \STATE compute $e=y-y^2$
                \STATE back propagate $e$ from right to left through layers
                \STATE update $w_i$
            \ENDWHILE
        \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Observe the use of the keywords (uppercase essential!) `\STATE`, `\FOR` and `\ENDFOR`, and `\WHILE` and `\ENDWHILE` as well as of LaTeX math notation, e.g.,  `\le` in place of `<=`, `\dots` in place of `…..`, and explicit subscript notation, e.g., `w_i` instead of `wi`. Finally, to display curly braces, use `\{` and `\}`, not `{` and `}`.

[image]

Comment: Please add a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled. If you post code here, put the code in the cursor and press the `{}` button to mark it as code.

Comment: @KersouMan - Many thanks for editing the answer and for bringing the code closer to being compilable. Unfortunately, it's still not fully compilable, as information is missing on what to do with `\State`, `\For`, `\While`, etc.

Comment: @Mico - Normally, with the last edit, it should work. The `algorithmic` environment requires full capital letters commands (`\STATE`, `\FOR`, etc.) to work.